# Does iOS 7 support Apple pay or is there any other good payment based API in iOS?

Tags: ios7, paypal, ios8, stripe-payments, applepay

I want to make an app with payment api i haven't experience the payment gateway apis.

Should i use Apple pay or any other open source api.

if other api then which could be the best suited for the enterprise application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Apple Pay handles the payment experience part on iOS apps, meaning you would have to integrate it with a payment platform (that supports Apple Pay) to complete the checkout solution and make it work for processing payments.

I'd recommend you to check with either [Braintree](http://www.braintreepayments.com/) or [Stripe](https://stripe.com/), both are pretty developer friendly for integration.

Comment: Thanks but apple pay supports the iOS 7?

Comment: Negative, apple pay has a minimun requirement on iOS SDK 8 and XCode   6.x